# How to pass OAuth credential to the reauthenticate method of Firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, object, firebase-authentication

I found some information on how to create the credentials object that is mentioned in the firebase docs but don't understand how to create the object if the user is authenticated with OAuth and not email and password. Does anyone know how this would work?

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
  user.email,
  'yourpassword'
);
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials);
```

Comment: Which OAuth provider do you want to create the credential for?

Comment: Any would be fine but let's say Facebook for example. Thank you!